# Registering remote method with relational model in strongloop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have 2 models, a `user` and a `messages` model. It's set up with a one-to-many relationship. This works great, and I can see all the default methods of messages under the user model in explorer.

The problem I have is that I've created a custom remote method `sendMessage`on the messages model. This works and I can access it under the `messages` model, but not for the `user` model. How do connect and access it?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what are you expecting/asking. Are you asking how to use the `sendMessage` method in user model in a remote method or how to have `sendMessage` as a method in user model?

Comment: How to have it so that sendMessage as a method in user model

Comment: What's the difference between calling `Message.sendMessage` and `User.sendMessage`?

Comment: User has all the ACLS with it etc. It's how i'd prefer it to be set up.

Comment: This might be a bug related to https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1130

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, superkhau was right. It's an issue with https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1130